# Can you blocking switch/assume role for console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I have a weird issue where I am not able to switch/assume role from account A to account B in the console but I mange to do so with CLI. Is it possible that it can be blocked somehow?

My first thought when I was able to assume the role in account B with CLI was that I had some cache messing with me but I cleared that but kept the issue.

To give fullt insight how I access my accounts I will describe my inlog "path":
First I login to our company's account (X) from here I assume a role in account (A). From here I'm not able to assume the role into account (B) with the help of the console but with CLI. Account A is a master account for B.

I still think this may be a local/browser error. But I just want to see if anyone knows if it possible to block assume role only for console?

The role in account B is as simpel it get with a trust policy for account A root.

Comment: For console you use IAM User. For CLI you use access keys. Do you use access keys that are generated for this IAM User?

Comment: No, that is not possible per-se. But there may be things that the console does not do that the CLI *is* able to do. E.g. set a different / specific session name, set the SourceIdentity, etc. Maybe some of those things are required but the console does not do those. You should investigate what the assume role policy document of the role in account B looks like. Anything else is just guess work.

Comment: @luk2302 The policy document is full admin policy. nothing weird with it. I will just continue to scratch my head and test weird things :)

Comment: Nope, that is not the **assume-role policy**. What you are referring to are the permission of the role. Check the assume-role policy / trust relationship.

Comment: Your wording made me a little confused but the trust policy is as simpel as it gets. with root access for the master account. No condition or anything else.